# PlotRange, polar plots and labelling

Tags: plotting

I have a dataset (of DNA reads corresponding to the human mitochondrial DNA) which I want to plot on a polar plot, with the distance corresponding to the G-C percentage of the DNA in that segment.

The raw data to generate the plot is:

```
plotArr = {{1, 1380, 1512, 48}, {2, 2501, 2687, 47}, {3, 15205, 15514, 47}, {4, 
  1390, 1129, 49}, {5, 5313, 5523, 42}, {6, 12948, 13165, 53}, {7, 
  14401, 14044, 43}, {8, 2207, 2525, 39}, {9, 7875, 8463, 44}, {10, 
  15528, 15943, 43}, {11, 9943, 9391, 46}, {12, 6238, 5515, 46}, {13, 
  16570, 15949, 45}, {13, 299, 1, 45}, {14, 1500, 2191, 41}, {15, 318,
   1143, 46}, {15, 276, 302, 46}, {16, 14392, 15217, 45}, {17, 13194, 
  14063, 46}, {18, 8430, 9408, 44}, {19, 11679, 12959, 43}, {20, 6208,
   7859, 45}, {21, 11681, 9918, 41}, {22, 5317, 3591, 45}, {22, 3566, 
  2667, 45}, {99, 0, 16570, 45.5}}
```

I then use a Show function to independently plot all of the DNA segments as arcs on the polar plot. This plots them correctly.

```
  Show[Table[
  PolarPlot[{plotArr[[i]][[4]]}, {t, plotArr[[i]][[2]]*Pi*2/16570, 
    plotArr[[i]][[3]]*Pi*2/16570}, PlotLabel -> plotArr[[i]][[1]]]
  , {i, Length[plotArr]}]]
```

[image]

However, adding the option PolarAxes->True completely messes the graph up.

[image]

Adding PlotRange -> {-50, 50} doesn't help, it changes the graph to this instead.

[image]

How do I correctly do this plot, so that it has a PolarAxes, and also a unified distance axis?

Also, what would be the best way to go about labelling each arc with its own label? (I attempted PlotLabel, but that only works for the entire plot)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try this also:

```
 plotArr = Sort[plotArr, #1[[4]] > #2[[4]] &];
    lable = Table[
       Text[Style[plotArr[[i]][[1]], Red, Bold], 
        plotArr[[i]][[4]] {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@
         Mean[{plotArr[[i]][[2]]*Pi*2/16570, 
           plotArr[[i]][[3]]*Pi*2/16570}]], {i, 1, Length[plotArr]}];
    Show[Table[
       PolarPlot[{plotArr[[i]][[4]]}, {t, plotArr[[i]][[2]]*Pi*2/16570, 
         plotArr[[i]][[3]]*Pi*2/16570}, PolarAxes -> (i == 1), 
        Epilog -> 
         Text[Style[plotArr[[i]][[1]], Red, Bold, 16], 
          plotArr[[i]][[4]] {Cos[#], Sin[#]} &@
           Mean[{plotArr[[i]][[2]]*Pi*2/16570, 
             plotArr[[i]][[3]]*Pi*2/16570}]]], {i, 1, 
        Length[plotArr]}]] /. Rule[Epilog, _] :> Rule[Epilog, lable]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I am not entirely sure I understand what you want but perhaps using `PolarAxes -> (i == 1)` does it?

```
Table[PolarPlot[{plotArr[[i]][[4]]}, {t, plotArr[[i]][[2]]*Pi*2/16570, 
    plotArr[[i]][[3]]*Pi*2/16570}, PlotLabel -> plotArr[[i]][[1]], 
   PolarAxes -> (i == 1)], {i, Length[plotArr]}] // Show
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, that's great. What about the other part of the question (labelling the arcs independently) though?

Comment: @March Where should the labels be?  There are so many segments that I have trouble imagining them all fitting.  Would Tooltips be useful?

Comment: The image is supposed to be exported, and not viewed within Mathematica, so I don't think Tooltips will help. There are only ~20 or so segments though, so I don't think that's too many?

Comment: @March Okay.  I am not trying to be obstinate but I still have trouble imagining it.  Would you be willing to manually draw labels for this one plot to illustrate what you would like?  I would then attempt to programmatically recreate it for application to other, similar plots.

Comment: @March What about coloring each segment uniquely and then using a legend?

Comment: I think colouring them will not be a good idea due to the large number of segments making it difficult to distinguish the colours. Could you just point me to the relevant labelling function for labelling a part of a line graph?

Comment: I think it might be especially bad on your side since your image is rather small, I intend to export this image on a much larger scale, so I think labelling is a reasonable option.

Comment: Actually Algohi has provided the answer, that was exactly what I had in mind.

Answer (score 3):

Although I understand the rationale for not wishing to distinguish curves by color, the approach below may be of interest to others.

```
plotscl = MapAt[N[# Pi*2/16570] &, plotArr, {{All, 3}, {All, 2}}];
Show[PolarPlot[Evaluate[Table[Piecewise[{{plotArr[[i, 4]], 
  Min[plotscl[[i, 2]], plotscl[[i, 3]]] < t < Max[plotscl[[i, 2]], plotscl[[i, 3]]]}}, I],
  {i, Length[plotArr]}]], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotRange -> 50, PlotPoints -> 100, 
  PlotLegends -> Cases[plotArr, {z_, _, _, _} -> z]], 
  PolarPlot[40, {t, 0, .0000001}, PlotRange -> 20, PolarAxes -> True], ImagePadding -> 50, 
  PlotRangeClipping -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: color plot]

Answer (score 1):

Rescale columns 2 and 3 to the interval `(0, 2 Pi)`:

```
{min, max} = Through@{Min, Max}@plotArr[[All, {2, 3}]];
(* {0, 16570} *)
data = MapAt[N[ Rescale[#, {min, max}, {0, 2 Pi}]] &, plotArr, {All, {2, 3}}];
```

Define two helper functions to be `Apply`ed to `data` to produce the polar plots and the text labels:

```
ClearAll[ppF, epilogF]
ppF[opts : OptionsPattern[PolarPlot]] := PolarPlot[{#4}, {t, #2, #3}, opts] &;
epilogF = Module[{m = Mean[{#2, #3}]}, Text[Style[#, Red, 16, Bold], #4 {Cos[m], Sin[m]}]] &;
```

Create an empty polar plot with the desired polar axes specification:

```
emptypp = PolarPlot[1, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle->None, Axes->False, BaseStyle->(FontSize->16),
                    PolarAxes -> True, PolarAxesOrigin -> {Pi/2, 60}];
```

Apply (`@@@`) `ppF` to rescaled data and overlay with `emptypp` using `Show` and setting `Epilog` option value to `epilogF@@@data`:

```
Show[emptypp, ppF[PlotStyle -> Dynamic[{Hue[RandomReal[]], Thick}]] @@@ data,
     ImageSize -> 600, Epilog -> (epilogF @@@ data)]
```

[image]

**Update:** You can also add the text labels using `Mesh`:

```
ClearAll[ppF2, meshF]
meshF[col_: Red, fsize_: 14, fweight_: Plain, ffamily_: "Arial"] := 
  Module[{m = Mean[{#2, #3}]}, 
        {{{Mean[{#2, #3}], 
           {col,PointSize[0], 
            FontSize -> fsize, FontWeight -> fweight, FontFamily -> ffamily,  
            Text[#, #4 {Cos[m], Sin[m]}]}}}}] &;

ppF2[opts:OptionsPattern[PolarPlot]] := PolarPlot[{#4}, {t, #2, #3}, opts, Mesh->(meshF[][##])] &;

Show[emptypp, ppF2[] @@@ data, Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 400]
```

[image]

Comment: If I need Matlab Type of Plots (https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polarplot.html),  how to set the parameters

Comment: @ABCDEMMM, see [PolarPlot](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PolarPlot.html). E.g. `PolarPlot[Sin[4 t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}]`

Comment: PolarPlot[yy, {x, 0, 2*Pi}, PolarAxes -> True, 
 PolarTicks -> {"Degrees", Automatic}, PolarGridLines -> True, 
 Mesh -> 15, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red]] I have done, thanks.