# Epilog does not work as expected with Show

Tags: plotting, graphics

I was trying to answer this question ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72304/plotrange-polar-plots-and-labelling)) and I found that I can't use `Epilog` with `Show`. consider this Example:

```
p1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[0.04], Point[{1, 0.5}]}]
```

[image]

```
p2 = Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 4}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{2, 0.5}]}]
```

[image]

```
Show[p1, p2]
```

[image]

It is clear that only `Epilog` of the first plot is taken.

Any idea why?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you already know how to combine the `Epilog`s manually so I didn't include that.

Answer (score 4):

This is consistent with how `Show` handles options in general.

`Show` will combine the graphics from the first (`p1`) and the second (`p2`) `Graphics` expression.  But all the *options* of the result will simply be inherited from the first one (`p1`).  The options of the second one (`p2`) are ignored.

`Epilog` is handled the same way as all the other options: it is inherited from `p1` and `p2`'s setting is ignored.

Comment: Exactly. Compare `Show[p1,p2]` to `Show[p2,p1]`.