# Epilog: Only one point appears in graph

Tags: plotting, graphics

I'm trying to graph something for a paper and I want to highlight two points in two function. I am using this code:

```
    Show[
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{x[0, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], 
      f[x[0, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], 50, .5, 1, .8, 3]}]}],
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[Large], 
    Point[{x[0, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], 
      f[x[0, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], 50, .5, .7, .8, 3]}]}]]
```

Where

```
x[cost_, t_, teta_, qa_, qv_, b_] := 
 2 Log[((3/2)*cost + 
      Sqrt[(cost^2)*(9/4) + 4 (((t - b) t)^1.5) (1 + teta) qa*qv])] - 
  2 Log[2 (1 + teta) qa (t - b)^1.5]

f[x_, t_, teta_, qa_, qv_, 
   b_] := ((t - b)^1.5)*
    qa*(1 + teta) E^(-1/8) (1 - Erf[(2 x - 1)/Sqrt[8]]) + (t^1.5)*qv*
    E^(-1/8)*(1 + Erf[(2 x + 1)/Sqrt[8]])
```

My output however only shows one of the points...Am I doing anything wrong or is it just the programme?
 [image: img]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related/duplicates: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72308/epilog-does-not-work-as-expected-with-show, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82471/plot-with-epilog-doesnt-show-up-in-show; https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128/plot-option-precedence-while-combining-plots-with-show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `Epilog` option for `Show` is taken from the first plot, so the one from the second plot is ignored. As alternative, simply specify the `Epilog` directly in `Show`.

```
epi1 = {Red, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{x[0, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], 
     f[x[0, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], 50, .5, 1, .8, 3]}]};
epi2 = {Green, PointSize[Large], 
   Point[{x[0, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], 
     f[x[0, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], 50, .5, .7, .8, 3]}]};
Show[
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}],
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}],
 Epilog -> {epi1, epi2},
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

[image]

Btw., this has the same effect and is somewhat more transparent to me:

```
Show[
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, .7, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}],
 Plot[f[x, 50, .5, 1, .8, 3], {x, -3, 3}],
 Graphics[{epi1, epi2}],
 PlotRange -> All
 ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome!